# How was Jezero crater selected?

Tags: mars, perseverance

[Perseverance is going to land in Jezero crater](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/). How was this landing site selected? I assume there were several landing sites that were considered, and different scientists wanted the rover to land in different places. What were they and what makes Jezero crater a better landing site than the other envisioned places?

Comment: [Closely related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28054/why-is-the-northeastern-region-of-syrtis-major-planum-a-selected-landing-site-fo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This NASA page](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/timeline/prelaunch/landing-site-selection/) describes the landing site selection process:

> At the third landing site workshop for the Mars 2020 rover mission on Feb. 8-10, 2017, a team of scientists narrowed down the list of potential places where NASA's Mars 2020 rover may land. Three sites were selected to continue as landing site candidates: Columbia Hills, Jezero Crater, NE Syrtis.

[This letter](https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/documents/Mars%202020%20landing%20site%20down-select%20Feb%202017.pdf) compares the final eight candidates. Jezero Crater is described as:

> a well-defined delta environment including the finest-grained facies deemed most favorable for organic concentration and preservation, a large and geologically diverse headwaters region emptying into an open, deep lake, and an intriguing carbonate-bearing unit that may preserve a record of the ancient martian carbon cycle.

The attributes that favoured Jezero Crater therefore seem to be that it is a geologically diverse site with clear evidence of flowing water emptying into a deep lake in the past.